# ArcGIS Tools Script Validation...filter list from domain values

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-toolbox, tool-validation

Anyone know if it's possible to build filter list from a set of coded domain values I have in a file geodatabase? I have a script that works taking values from a table and correctly building a filter list but i'm not sure how to access the domain values?

```
FIELDS = ["Name", "Title", "Organisation", "Address1", "Address2", "Address3", "Town", "PostCode", "Telephone", "EMail"]
TABLE = (r"P:\Photo-Share\New_Projects_Database.gdb\Customer")

rows = arcpy.SearchCursor(TABLE)
self.params[3].filter.list = sorted(list(set(r.getValue('Organisation') for r in rows)))
del rows
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to convert the domain values to a list directly. However, as an intermediate step, you could convert your domain to a table using the [DomainToTable](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/domain-to-table.htm) tool, then convert that table to a list using a [Search Cursor](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/functions/searchcursor.htm).

Comment: thanks for the help, thats the route i've ended up going down